# 16.04: Network connection drops after attempting to sync files via Samba

Tags: networking, samba

I have an old windows laptop that I installed 16.04 on from a minimal cd. Because the wifi drivers were not available I used an Edimax dongle to connect to the network over wifi. The goal was to replace an existing raspberry pi samba NAS with this old laptop in the hopes of faster transfer speeds. However every time I try to sync files to the Ubuntu machine using an Android App "Syncme" I get a network timeout and then connection to the network drops. At that point I'm no longer able to SSH into the computer and wget google.com no longer yields a connection. It will continue showing that it is connected to the wireless network though. If I remove and reinsert the dongle it will reconnect to wifi and start working again. I ended up following some instructions to replace the rtl drivers for the dongle which did seem to fix random network drops that I was having before in conjunction with the network timeouts. So far I've been unable to sync to the Ubuntu machine where I have no problems with a raspberry pi in the same configuration. I have also disabled ipv6 in the network options. I am a linux noob... Any thoughts?

Comment: I am wondering if the issue might be a issue with the drives pulling too much power when writing and that's causing issues with the wifi dongle.